# How to make mathematical in rest parameter?

Tags: javascript, rest, math, ecmascript-6, parameters

```
function sum(a,...all){
    return a-5-all;
}
console.log(sum(5,10,12));
```

Result Is Nan, I want this code to give me the correct mathematical result with "rest parameter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all` is an array. Here's a better way that uses the higher-order `reduce` function. (Search it on MDN.)

```js
function sum(...numbers) {
    return numbers.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);
}
```

This is more elegant and overall a better solution because we know what's going on, and we only have one rest parameter and no regular parameter.